# CLOSE_WAIT connection terminate without killing software

Tags: php, networking, tcp

Due to circumstances (having to do with proxied tcp connections) I regularly end up with CLOSE_WAIT connections. Usually caused by my browser during debugging.

The tunnels are started by a PHP script, which can detect these CLOSE_WAIT states so it can show an error and not try to reuse that port (since "program X" is keeping it busy). It's fairly easy to kill the associated program, but I'd prefer not to as it takes a lot of time to setup again.

There is this [perl script](https://github.com/rghose/kill-close-wait-connections) that sends fake "ACK"-packets so the programs close the connection assuming it is terminated. Is there any way to accomplish this in PHP:

```
my $packet = Net::RawIP->new({
   ip => { frag_off => 0, tos => 0, saddr => $dst_ip, daddr => $src_ip},
   tcp => { dest => $src_port, source => $dst_port, seq => 10, ack => 1}
});
$packet->send;
```

Like I said: I have all details, it's just the actual packet generation and sending it that I need. I'd like to avoid having to externally trigger a perl script from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use create_socket() with SOCK_RAW.

But, setting of headers(IP/TCP) must be raw data. That is difficult.

[PRNL(PHP Raw Network Library)](https://github.com/martijnb/prnl) can make it easier.